# Why is my javascript failing to upload an image and put it in a canvas element with this code?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, upload

```
function addMoreFileUploads(id){
    var canvasName =  'canvas' + id;
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasName);



    $("#fileUploads").append('<input id="' + id + '" type="file" name="files[]" /> <br><br>');

    $("#canvasInsert").append('<canvas id="'+ canvasName +'" style="border:1px solid #000000;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>');

    var imageLoader = document.getElementById(id); //OnChange="upl()" 

    imageLoader.addEventListener('change',
        function(e){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event){
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function(){
                    //canvas.width = img.width;
                    //canvas.height = img.height;
                    //ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
                }
                img.src = event.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);   
        },false);
}
```

Trying to make it so that when I add an input element, it also attaches an event listener to it that looks for an image then reads it into a canvas element which has already been created.

Ideas??

Comment: Looks like you're initializing the variable "canvas" *before* you add the `<canvas>` element to the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasName);
```

Will be null since in your DOM there is no canvas element at this point

```
function addMoreFileUploads(id){

    var canvasName =  'canvas' + id;

    $("#fileUploads").append('<input id="' + id + '" type="file" name="files[]" /> <br><br>');
    $("#canvasInsert").append('<canvas id="'+ canvasName +'" style="border:1px solid #000000;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>');

    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasName),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var imageLoader = document.getElementById(id); //OnChange="upl()" 

    imageLoader.addEventListener('change',
        function(e){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event){
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function(){
                    canvas.width = img.width;
                    canvas.height = img.height;
                    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
                }
                img.src = event.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);   
        },false);
}

addMoreFileUploads('foo');
```

There were more bugs. Here is a working code but in my opinion is pretty messed up, even if it works.

Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/LqjLD/1/**

Comment: Thanks, good spot. 
I now get the issue that e is not defined.. Ideas?

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle. Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9UnzT/1/ There you go. It doesn't seem to work from JSFiddle though. It does locally when you change the number of rows.

Comment: I don't understand, what did you change??

Comment: @Chris G You need to get the canvas element after it is added to the DOM. Your canvas content, ctx, was not defined. Image drawing was commented. A final demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/LqjLD/1/

Comment: Erm, sorry to be a pain but it still isn't working in my code but it works in the fiddle and I don't know why.. I see you're using JQuery, I guess that could be it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45509/discussion-between-chris-g-and-mircea)

Comment: You also need to call addMoreFileUploads('foo') with a parameter. http://jsfiddle.net/9UnzT/2/. Yes, your code needs jQuery to work in jsFiddle.